# Auto checked table when all checkboxes are checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm fairly new in jQuery. Basically I have a few tables and I have to make last checkbox for each table checked when all of the elements of a table are checked. 
Here is a simple demo that is the result that I want. 
Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rc1hwk4/7/)

So far this is what I did, but it still checked for my last checkbox although the elements of that field are not checked all of them.

```
$('table tr:last-child input:checkbox').closest('table').find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('table tr:last-child input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
        }
});
```

Comment: I just edited from the demo above, you may check it out. The checkbox should be selected when all of the elements are selected.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I got it, sorry and thanks for your remind.

Comment: @Ethen check out the fiddle link below optimized and compatible.

Comment: @Ethen, I rephrased my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this demo- http://jsfiddle.net/5h25ngvw/

I separated checkboxes with the class named `group` and the one at bottom row with `parent`

**Find the length of checked input(s)** containing class `.group`.

```
$('table').find('.group:checked').length
```

**Length of all underlying checkboxes in current table-**

```
$('table').find('.group').length
```

**How this works-**

Assume you have 12 checkboxes and 8 are checked out of them, Now you check the length in respect to all checkboxes as `if(12==8)?then check the bottom one :else remained unchecked.`

**On load of document**

Now the on load event is directly checking in each table with the same logic above. It iterates each table and finds all checked and unchecked checkboxes and compares whether the length is equal for both of them.

```
$('.group').change(function(){
        if($(this).closest('table').find('.group:checked').length==$(this).closest('table').find('.group').length){
        $(this).closest('table').find('input[class="parent"]').prop('checked','checked')
        }
        else
        {
       $(this).closest('table').find('input[class="parent"]').prop('checked',false);
        }

    });
```

**onload load event for checkboxes-**

```
$('table').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('input.group').length==$(this).find('input:checked').length){
    $(this).find('input.parent').prop('checked',true);
    }
});
```

Additionally, I would cut the code down and will update you with minimized one

Comment: [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s2wfxo7b/1/) From your example above, you may check out it doesn't work and i just removed table 2 of checked.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank you very much! Can you please put some comment to describe your code? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Ethen, Yeah sure, Let me do it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/3rc1hwk4/9/

**JS:-**

```
//change event handler for the checkbox in the last tr 

$('table tr:last-child input:checkbox').change(function () {
    //use closest to find the table containing the changed checkbox and set the checked value for each checkbox in that table to the new status
    $(this).closest('table').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('table tr:last-child input:checkbox').closest('table').find('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") && !$(this).is(":last-child")) {
        $('table tr:last-child input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rc1hwk4/11/)  you can see from here, it still cannot be selected

Answer (score 0):

Try out this Fidle https://jsfiddle.net/3rc1hwk4/28/

I have applied a class to TRs having checkboxes "" with the exception of that last TR. Here is my code

```js
//change event handler for the checkbox in the last tr 
$('table tr:last-child input:checkbox').change(function(){
    //use closest to find the table containing the changed checkbox and set the checked value for each checkbox in that table to the new status
    $(this).closest('table').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
}); 
$('table tr.checkboxes td input:checkbox').change(function(){
    var all_checked = true;
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr.checkboxes input:checkbox').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            all_checked = false;    
        }
    });
    if (all_checked) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('tr:last-child input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    } else {
        $(this).closest('table').find('tr:last-child input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>System Setting</td>
        <td>(View Action)</td>
        <td>(Add Action)</td>
        <td>(Update Action)</td>
        <td>(Delete Action)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkboxes">
        <td>1. Manage Main Module</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkboxes">
        <td>2. Manage Sub Module</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <tr class="last-checkbox">
            <td colspan="5" align="right">
                <input type="checkbox">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" id="second-table">
    <tr>
        <td>Manage Setting</td>
        <td>(View Action)</td>
        <td>(Add Action)</td>
        <td>(Update Action)</td>
        <td>(Delete Action)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="checkboxes">
        <td>1. Manage Setting</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked>
        </td>
        <tr class="last-checkbox">
            <td colspan="5" align="right">
                <i>I have to make this checkbox checked when all of the elements are checked</i><input type="checkbox" id="MYID" checked>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
            
            More and More tables.......
```